# jqPlot: Overlapping Series

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqplot

I have an issue with the jqPlot.

I want to plot dates as a series. I have always to points (a begin and an end date).

But when I have to series with the same dates or part of the date range is the same, the series will be overlapping each other.

Is there a solution to have a space between the series.

My code:

```
var plot1 = $.jqplot('activityChart', [[["30.09.2008", "Eins"], ["30.10.2008", "Eins"]], [["30.11.2008", "Zwei"], ["30.12.2008", "Zwei"]], [["01.09.2008", "Eins"], ["30.10.2008", "Eins"]]], {
    title : 'Activity Plan',
    axes : {
        xaxis : {
            renderer : $.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer                    
        },
        yaxis: {
            renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer                        
        }
    },
    cursor: {
        show: true,
        zoom: true,
        showTooltip: true,
        dblClickReset: true,
        looseZoom:true
    },
    series: [{
        lineWidth: 4, 
        markerOptions: {
            style: 'square'
        }
    }, {
       lineWidth: 4,
       markerOptions: {
            style: 'diamond'
       }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this trick :

```
//Take out HTML content of entire legend
var text = jQuery("table[class='jqplot-table-legend']").html();

//Stick it to the Legend Div Tag - of page
//create a div tag with id='jqplotctrl_legend'
jQuery('#jqplotctrl_legend').html(text); 

//Set original jQPlot legend to empty 
jQuery("table[class='jqplot-table-legend']").html('');
```